# awk, newline insert based on range of previous line starts

Tags: awk

I want to insert a new line containing just + after every occurrence of a line starting with A, T, G or C

I can do this one at a time using the below code (where the example code would just apply to lines starting with A):

```
awk 'a=/^A/{b=1}b&&!a{print "+";b=0}1'
```

How do you make an awk command like this take several options for a line start? i.e. A or T or G or C

example input:

```
1242345£$$%&£2345235%$^  
@asjksfkjcke-vse-segsgs-  
AGCTGCTAGGCTAGCCAACTG  
1263£%&££1124$^&&"£2112123423%%  
@asdasasf--sd--sdgsdga-  
GCTAGCCTAGGCTTCGAGGCCCCGATTC  
"£%&"!!""^!35£$^12357"£$^
```

Output:

```
1242345£$$%&£2345235%$^  
@asjksfkjcke-vse-segsgs-  
AGCTGCTAGGCTAGCCAACTG  
+  
1263£%&££1124$^&&"£2112123423%%  
@asdasasf--sd--sdgsdga-  
GCTAGCCTAGGCTTCGAGGCCCCGATTC  
+    
"£%&"!!""^!35£$^12357"£$^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following(couldn't test it since samples are not provided).

```
awk '/^A/ || /^T/ || /^G/ || /^C/{print $0 ORS;next} 1' Input_file
```

OR

```
awk '/^A|^T|^G|^C/{$0=$0 ORS} 1' Input_file
```

In case you need to print `+` in new line then change `ORS` to `ORS "+"` in above codes.

Comment: Sorry, I've adjusted my question to highlight exactly what I'm trying to do

Comment: @Giles, already edited please see my comment change `ORS` to `ORS "+"` i codes and let me know then?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '1; /^[ATGC]/{print "+"}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk

```
awk ' /^[ATGC]/ { $(NF+1)="\n+" }1 '
```

with the given inputs

```
$ cat giles.txt
1242345£$$%&£2345235%$^
@asjksfkjcke-vse-segsgs-
AGCTGCTAGGCTAGCCAACTG
1263£%&££1124$^&&"£2112123423%%
@asdasasf--sd--sdgsdga-
GCTAGCCTAGGCTTCGAGGCCCCGATTC
"£%&"!!""^!35£$^12357"£$^

$ awk ' /^[ATGC]/ { $(NF+1)="\n+" }1 ' giles.txt
1242345£$$%&£2345235%$^
@asjksfkjcke-vse-segsgs-
AGCTGCTAGGCTAGCCAACTG
+
1263£%&££1124$^&&"£2112123423%%
@asdasasf--sd--sdgsdga-
GCTAGCCTAGGCTTCGAGGCCCCGATTC
+
"£%&"!!""^!35£$^12357"£$^

$
```